# How to Handle Mutltiple Query Parameters for the same endpoint with Springboot and JPA

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I am currently studying Springboot so I am developing a personal project. In this Project a Have an entity named Campaign and I want to build a endpoint to list all campaigns in the database filtering, sorting and paginating

Some examples of requests:

```
# Pagination 

GET domain/api/v1/campaigns (return the first page with  all campaigns, default sorting and page size 20)
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?page=2&size=50 (return the second page with all campaigns, default sorting and page size 50)
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?page=2&size=100 (return the second page with all campaigns, default sorting and page size 50 which is the max)


# SORTING
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?sort=name,asc (return the first page with all campaigns, sorting by name and page size 20)
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?sort=name,asc&sort=startDate,dsc (return the first page with all campaigns, sorting by name and startDate and page size 20) 

# Filtering

GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?status=open (return the first page with all campaigns with "open" status, default sorting and page size 20)
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?status=open&status=new (return the first page with all campaigns with "open" and "new" status,default sorting and page size 20)
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?status=open&startdate=2023-01-12 (return the first page with all campaigns with "open" status and startDate 2023-01-12, default sortin and page size 20)

# Combined
GET domain/api/v1/campaigns?status=open&status=new&page=2&size=10&sort=name,asc (returns page 2 with size 10 sorting by name the campaigns with statuses "open" and "new")
```

Which is the best way to implement this? A single Controller method that delegates to the correct service method based on the parameters? Collecting the parameters on a HashMap and create a generic Query for the database that deals with the parameters?  Many different controllers that receive a diffent set of parameters?

Here is mt Campign Model and empty Repository, Service And Controller

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGNS")
public class Campaign {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
    private String status;
}
```

```java
public interface CampaignRepository extends JpaRepository<Campaign, Long> {

}
```

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CampaignService {
    private final CampaignRepository campaignRepository;
```

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/campaigns")
public class CampaignController {
    private final CampaignService campaignService;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build a dynamic query. In this case, not only can you accomplish this with a single controller method, but you will also only need one service method with the use of Specifications. Additionally, you can retrieve certain pages and limit its size with the `Page<T>` interface and the `PageRequest` class

`CampaignController.java`:

```java
// receive all possible arguments
public Page<Campaign> filterCampaigns(..., Pageable pageable) {
    return campaignService.getCampaignsByCriteria(..., pageable.getPageNumber());
}
```

You can pass all possible URL parameters to the controller method. To execute specifications, `CampaignRepository` will need to extend the `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` interface. Paginating campaigns will require another interface `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>`

`CampaignRepository.java`

```java
public interface CampaignRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Campaign, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Campaign>, 
PagingAndSortingRepository<Campaign, Long> {

}
```

Following this, create a helper class that defines these specifications. Here's an example for finding by status, but you can have as many specifications as necessary

`CampaignSpecification.java`

```java
public static Specification<Campaign> hasStatus(String campaignStatus) {
    return startDate == null ? null : (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> 
        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status"), campaignStatus);

}
```

Returning the specification ***if a status value is provided*** or returning null otherwise makes it flexible because the `status` URL parameter is essentially optional this way. It's also worth noting that this is applicable for every parameter in the method. Now, you can execute this specification in the service.

`CampaignService.java`

```java
public Page<Campaign> getCampaignsByCriteria(String status, 
                                            LocalDateTime startDate, 
                                            int pageNumber) {

    PageRequest campaignPageRequest = PageRequest
        .of(pageNumber, 2, Sort.by("startDate").ascending());

    return campaignRepository.findAll(Specification.where(
        CampaignSpecification.hasStatus(status).
        and(CampaignSpecification.hasSomethingElse(...)))
        , campaignPageRequest)
    )
}
```

You can chain as many specifications as you need. The `PageRequest` class allows you to specify the current page, the maximum number of items for each page, as well as perform sorting

Further reading:

[Spring Data Specification](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

[Page interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)

[PageRequest class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)

Answer (score 1):

For paging and sorting, the Spring Framework comes with good support:

```
public interface CampaignRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Campaign, Long> {

}
```

[PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)

This provides you the possibility to append a Pageable to the methods. E.g. if you want to page through results filtered by status:

```
public interface CampaignRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Campaign, Long> {

    List<Campaign> findAllByStatusIn(Collection<String> status, Pageable pageRequest);

}
```

Your Service can then easily prepare such a pageable, for example:

```
public List<Campaign> listByStatusSorted(Collection<String> status, int page, int pageSize, String sortProperty) {

    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(sortProperty).ascending());
    return campaignRepository.findAllByStatusIn(status, pageRequest);

}
```

[PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html), [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)

Sorting ascending or descending can also be provided from the controller to the service of course. But in essence I would have one or two service methods. I think this is a matter of taste where you'd rather have another service method instead of adding ever more parameters.

I would try to mostly use one controller endpoint with default values. Something along the lines of:

```
public List<Campaign> listCampaigns(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false, defaultValue = "20") int pageSize, ...) {
    ...
}
```

Going by this, absolutely none of

> Collecting the parameters on a HashMap and create a generic Query for the database that deals with the parameters

is needed. By using the naming conventions all is done for you. In fact, the repository I provided above should already work without any further code - just inject it in the service. [Further reading on the power of Spring Data Repositories.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the annotation @RequestParam in your controller. It would be something like:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/campaigns")
@ResponseBody
public String CampaignController(@RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page, @RequestParam (name = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "50") Integer size) {
return "page: " + page;
}
```